# How to force image url in jasper report export to HTML?

Tags: html, image, url, jasper-reports

A report uses images on a web-server (but not necessarily the application's web-server). The report has an image element expression as follows:

```
"http://www.example.de/images/" + $F{picture}
```

When I export the report to HTML using the `JRXhtmlExporter` and display the generated HTML in a browser, the image is not visible. When I inspect the img tag with firebug the src parameter is not the same as the expression but some generated folder and generated file name. If the report is exported to PDF via `JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream()` the image is displayed correctly in the resulting PDF file.

I set **`JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_OUTPUT_IMAGES_TO_DIR`** to `Boolean.FALSE`, but it didn't help.

How can I force that the image url stays the same while exporting?

**Note:** The "Is Lazy" [option](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/images/index.html) the iReport does what I want.

Answer (score 4):

The key is setting the **isLazy** property to **true** (as indicated by @ThomasKessler in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003308/1238957)). This works for me and generates the three reports (PDF, XLS, HTML) flawlessly.

I do the following:

**.jrxml**

```
...
<parameter name="LOGO_URL" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
...
<image isLazy="true">
  <reportElement uuid="24062838-1ede-4578-acdf-9a63662ea738" x="0" y="0" width="108" height="30"/>
   <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{LOGO_URL}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
...
```

In a **.properties** file I have configured (for each environment):

```
my.logo.url=http://localhost:8080/MySite/img/my_logo.jpg
```

In a **Servlet**, I have 3 methods: *generatePDFReport, generateXLSReport* and *generateHTMLreport*. In this last one, I have:

```
            Properties prop = Configurator.getProperties(BUNDLENAME);
            Connection con = ReportsDB.getConnection();
            String reportPathTag = prop.getProperty(Report.JASPERURL);

            Map parameters = Report.extractJasperParams(request.getParameterMap());
            String jasperPath = parameters.containsKey(reportPathTag) ? (String) parameters.get(reportPathTag) : "";
            String reportName = parameters.containsKey(Report.JASPERTITLE) ? (String) parameters.get(Report.JASPERTITLE) : "myReport";

            String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
            path += jasperPath;

            JasperReport jasperReport = null;
            JasperDesign jasperDesign = null;
            jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(path);

            logFilteringCard(parameters);

            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, con);
            JRHtmlExporter htmlExporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
            htmlExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
            htmlExporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN, Boolean.FALSE);            
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            htmlExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_WRITER, pw);
            htmlExporter.exportReport();
            con.close();
```

And in the line:

```
Map parameters = Report.extractJasperParams(request.getParameterMap());
```

I set all the parameters of the report, including **LOGO_URL**, setting the properties value.

In my case I use this generic method to generate all the reports I need. The method **Report.extractJasperParams** uses the *request*'s map to reflect which report should be generated and sets the parameters accordingly, but you can simplify it for you specific needs.

The method **Configurator.getPoperties()** is to simplify the loading of the **Properties** file (in my case a file with some encrypted values).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the standard solution is to implement a way to serve up your images. Refer to this sample that ships with JasperReports: `demo/samples/webapp`.

But if you're willing to pass in a parameter so that you can use Lazy Loading for the HTML but not for PDF, then that will certainly work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and resolved the issue with the new Jasper API. [Here](http://helicaltech.com/adding-images-to-html-in-jasper-reports/) is the blog article corresponding to it. The problem was resolved using the new API and by using ImageServlet configuration in the web.xml.