# Spring mvc jasper reports

Tags: spring, jasper-reports

I am using spring mvc 4.1.7 pure java annotations config with jasper reports 5.0 and spring data jpa
I want to achieve pagination when rendering the report as html. I have a 
JasperReportsViewResolver bean configured as follows

```
@Bean(name="jasperResolver")
public JasperReportsViewResolver getJasperReportsViewResolver() {
    Map<String,Object> exporterParameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    exporterParameters.put("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN",Boolean.FALSE);

    JasperReportsViewResolver resolver = new JasperReportsViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/reports/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jasper");
    resolver.setReportDataKey("datasource");
    resolver.setViewNames("rpt_*");
    resolver.setViewClass(JasperReportsMultiFormatView.class);
    resolver.setExporterParameters(exporterParameters);
    resolver.setOrder(0);
    return resolver;
}
```

and in my controller i have

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/report")
public class ReportsController {

@Autowired
ClientsRepository clientsRepository;


@RequestMapping("/clients")
public String getClientReport(ModelMap modelMap,Model model)
{
    modelMap.put("datasource", clientsRepository.findAll());
    modelMap.put("format", "html");

    model.addAttribute(modelMap);

    return  "rpt_clients";
}
```

The problem i am having here is that the report has an image placed in the same directory but it is not being located leading to the exception

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at : invoice_logo.png
```

the other issue is implementing basic pagination for the report probably using a PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver

Comment: For pagination in html also see JRHtmlExporterParameter.BETWEEN_PAGES_HTML deprecated but since you use IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN who gives.....

Comment: Thanks Petter Fiberg. your solution works for pdf exports but for html the image src attribute shows a "nullimg_0_0_19"

Comment: Have you checked this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141222/how-to-force-image-url-in-jasper-report-export-to-html

Comment: @Petter Friberg 
The lazy option tries to access the image as a local resource instead of the web server.
I added 

    exporterParameters.put("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI", context.getContextPath()+"/resources/reportsimages/");

now the link comes up as 
<img src="/capital/resources/reportsimages/img_0_0_19">

where is img_0_0_19 coming from instead of the image name invoice_logo.png

Comment: If you solved, your problems, I suggest that you pass it as an answer if you feel it can be useful for other users... note however that you are using deprecated metods... maybe time to swtich?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I took your suggestion to use the isLazy option and i passed the url to the image resource and it worked like a charm. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I am using older methods because spring context support in my experience is not updated to work with the new exporter parameters. It keeps throwing a class not found exception when i use 

    "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.html.using.images.to.align"  

for instance.

Comment: Spring context?, for me it depends of version of jasper library and I would guess that you can update it..

Comment: I tried it with jasper reports 6.1.1 and 6.2.0